# Moving scrollbar downward through click translates modal along y-axis

Tags: css, css-transforms, blueimp, bootstrap-image-gallery

I am using [bootstrap image gallery](https://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/) to display images on my website. I have added an extra column for comments (with scrollbar) so that users may comment on photo.

**Probelm:**

When i click on scroll-bar to scroll, whole modal move downwards/upwards due to css transform style applied on slide ( cannot find js code from where this style is appended ).

Here is a code of each slide

```
<div class="slide" data-index="0" style="width: 1366px; left: 0px; 
transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);"> 
<...Modal Code ...>
```

Any suggestions how to overcome ....

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwk7Lmkk/3/)

[image]

Comment: could you post a link to the site or provide a fiddle?

Comment: @nifal http://jsfiddle.net/fwk7Lmkk/3/

Comment: Which scrollbar are u referring to? cause I dont see a scrollbar